# Entering data into a textfile from mysql using scripts

Tags: mysql, scripting

I have written a script to extract the contents of a table into a textfile. this is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -uroot -ppasswd database select * from table>textfile.txt
```

i have changed permissions on the file and when i run it using `./myscript` it creates textfile.txt but loads into it the mysql manual.How can i achieve my desired result. I am using Linux cli

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump` provides --tab option which will let you write data into `csv` as well as txt. Basically what you can do

`mysqldump -u root -ppassword --tab=/PATH/TO/FOLDER/ database_name table_name`

`--tabs` will give you options like `--fields-terminated-by` and `--fields-enclosed-by` which will help you modify the output you desire.

see `mysqldump --help` for other options.

Also you have to make sure that the folder should be writable by mysqld user.

This may work as well

`mysql -u root -ppassword db_name -e "select * from table"`